# Why finding the shortest solution for a linear Diophantine equation is a NP problem?

Tags: np-complete

[image: https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=Why+is+linear+programming+is+NP+problem%3F]

I read this paper saying: ...finding the shortest solution for a linear Diophantine equation is a NP problem?

**I have two questions:**

1). What it means of "the shortest solution" for linear Diophantine equation?

2). Dose it means if we don't purse "the shortest solution" for a linear Diophantine equation, then solving linear Diophantine equation will be a P problem?

The complete paper link is:
https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/2383100.pdf

Comment: A bad abstract , since it does not clarify non-standard terminologies. I have no idea either what "shortest" means in this context.

Comment: Might be it is. The complete paper link: https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/2383100.pdf